# У черта на рогах. А почему именно НА РОГАХ?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

**У черта на куличках (на рогах)**.  Разг.
Очень далеко, в отдаленных, глухих местах (быть, жить, селиться и т. п.).
[Фразеологический словарь русского языка](https://books.google.ee/books?id=fZe8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA363&lpg=PA363&dq=%D0%A3%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20(%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%85).%20%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE,%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85,%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85%20(%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C,%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C,%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82.%D0%BF.%20).&source=bl&ots=P_OhBcFFqW&sig=ACfU3U154cDRqg-cBNP76wgT1Bktxow9Hg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1k8fMx4jxAhXUm4sKHZEmCgAQ6AEwCXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%A3%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20(%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%85).%20%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%2C%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85%20(%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82.%D0%BF.%20).&f=false)

А почему именно **на рогах**,  а не на ушах, на шее, на хвосте, на копытах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На такой вопрос трудно ответить. Наверное потому, что так сложилось в языке.
Кстати, совсем не обязательно "у черта на рогах". "К черту в пекло", "к черту за подкладку" и многое другое существует. Да и значение не такое уж однозначное.

Еще можете вот тут посмотреть.

> Кстати, у Даля это звучит так: «Везде бывал: не был только у черта на
>   рогах». Согласитесь, что это не обязательно «далеко-далеко», как в
>   современном толковании выражения, -- скорее, в очень необычном месте.

http://gramota.ru/forum/kurilka/102054/

Можно предположить, что все выражения порождены выражением "К черту" с дальнейшим расширением-уточнением "на рога", "на кулички" и прочее. И отсюда уже преобразованием "куда" в "где" получены остальные формы.

Рога же, видимо, более характерная принадлежность черта, поэтому они более популярны в сравнении с копытами. Вряд ли в том есть глубинный смысл.

Вот здесь есть кое-что по теме, правда не совсем предметно по вопросу.
http://cheloveknauka.com/frazeologizmy-s-komponentami-bog-i-chert-v-sovremennom-russkom-yazyke 
(Это не та Шведова, как вы понимаете, хоть и Наталия)

Comment: господи,  КАК же Вы ее  "выцарапали",  ту - не ту Шведову?!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Это гугл. А "та" Шведова - известный лингвист, поэтому предостерег от ошибочного приписывания авторства.

Comment: Своим сообщением я только хотела сделать Вам комплимент - за исчерпывающий ответ и предоставленный автореферат. Со временем я его обязательно проштудирую.  А  спутать Наталью Владимировну с Наталией Юльевной невозможно.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова - ок, понятно. на самом деле ответ меня самого не совсем устраивает, поскольку основное - на уровне догадок. А еще Вы учтите, что ваши комплименты могу читать не только я, не все поймут одинаково. А то тут вдруг стали как-то резко нетерпимо относиться к обсуждению...  Короче, комплименты сюда - evgen_kostromin@mail.ru ))))

Answer (score 2):

Потому что рога - самая яркая деталь его облика, когда не хотят произносить вслух его имя, иногда говорят "этот, который с рогами".

Когда-то было достаточно произнести первую часть идиомы, и становилось понятно, что это место неопределённо далёкое и опасное.  Увеличение компонентного состава фразеологизма путем введения дополнительных компонентов - один из способов преобразования фразеологизмов писателями {к черту в пекло, к черту в подкладку - Н.В. Гоголь, к черту на помойку — А.Н. Житинский). Уточняющие компоненты - результат семантического «перенапряжения» фразеологизма, средство усиления экспрессии.«Когда само название немытика недостаточно точно указывает на его «адрес» [Мокиенко 1980: 48], тогда в компонентный состав качественно-обстоятельственного фразеологизма включается второй именной компонент с предлогом со значением места". Это делает образ более конкретным: к черту в мешок, к черту на кулички, к черту в пекло, к черту на рога, к чертям собачьим, ко всем чертям, к черту в подкладку, хоть к черту на рога.

Усиление экспрессивности обычно происходит путем активизации значения второго именного компонента.  Оттенки у идиом разные. У чёрта на куличках(на кулижках - бросовых землях в глуши, болотах, где только черти водились)- акцент на даль, неизвестность.К чёрту на рога - акцент на неопределённость, опасность, самую близость к нечисти.

Comment: Увеличение компонентного состава фразеологизма путем введения дополнительных компонентов - один из способов преобразования фразеологизмов писателями {к черту в пекло, к черту в подкладку - Н.В. Гоголь, к черту на помойку — А.Н. Житинский).  Это отсюда http://www.dissercat.com/content/frazeologizmy-s-komponentami-bog-i-chert-v-sovremennom-russkom-yazyke

Answer (score 1):

*Кулички*, с одной стороны, намекают на отдалённость — Церковь Всех Святых на Кулишках построена была за границей Китай-города в XIV в., а слово *кулишки* было синонимом местонахождения — «на краю земли». С другой стороны, слова *коула* (= башня, замок, крепость), *куль*, *кулёк* (= конус) связывают *кулички* с формой рожка.

Мы имеем дело с синонимами: быть посланным что на рога, что на кулички парнокопытному — разницы нет, адрес тот же.

Comment: Пусть с опозданием, но — спасибо за Ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Раз написано «на рогах» в скобках возможно происхождение общее с «на куличках». Я думаю, «у чёрта» стало ассоциироваться с далеко, потому что им пугали, чтоб не заходили далеко. [«У чёрта на куличках»](https://xn----7sbfc3aaqnhaffdukg9p.xn--p1ai/blog/istoriya-krylatogo-vyrazheniya-u-cherta-na-kulichkah-):

> У черта на куличках. Должно быть, не всем известно, что же такое
> кулички. В старину так называли те места в лесу, которые были наиболее
> болотистыми и вязкими. Именно там, по преданиям, и водилась всякая
> нечистая сила во главе с чертом. **Поэтому друг другу строго наказывали
> – не забираться в лес слишком далеко и глубоко**, не плутать в трех
> соснах, ибо дьявол силен.

Так «у чёрта» стало синонимом «далеко».

Дело в том, что раньше пропажу взрослых людей и детей объясняли проявлениями нечистой силы, которая водится в лесах и на болотах.

Для примера можно почитать про Кикимору в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0):

> Это в основном маленькая, уродливая, скрюченная, неопрятная,
> растрёпанная, худая, остроносая, неряшливая, в лохмотьях немолодая
> женщина или старуха, покрытая тиной, болотными травами и
> мхом, живущая в непроходимых топях в лесных чащах, пугающая
> неприятными голосами, воем, вызывающая беспричинный страх,
> **заставляющая блуждать по лесу, заманивающая в трясину и похищающая
> маленьких детей.**

Люди могли пугать близких и детей, что б те не заходили далеко в лес, тем что там живёт нечистая сила (чёрт и т. п.), которая может их погубить.

А на рогах возможно по тому, что там как раз оказывался тот кто, зашёл в лес слишком далеко и попался чёрту, который его поднял на рога.

Возможно «у чёрта на рогах», говорили про того, кто пропал — зашёл слишком далеко в лес или на болота и попал к чёрту, который его поднял на рога (погубил).

Например:
— Где Пётр?
— У чёрта на рогах.

Comment: Долгое время вопрос не вызывал интереса. Благодарю за мнение.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Мне показался вопрос интересным. То, что сейчас считается фразеологизмом (сочетанием слов, из значения которых нельзя вывести напрямую смысл выражения), часто раньше имело ясный смысл, который забылся. Для меня удивительно, что люди повторяют в речи, казалось бы, бессмысленные сочетания слов. Хочется докопаться до сути, почему так говорят, откуда это пошло.